# Has 'Arab media' reported the execution of the leader of the Dogmush clan by Hamas?

Tags: media, israel-hamas-war, hamas, gaza

The *Times of Israel* reported on March 14 [that](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/arab-media-reports-hamas-executed-local-clan-member-in-gaza-city/)

> Arab media reports: Hamas ‘executed’ local clan member in Gaza City
>
> Hamas has killed the leader of the powerful Doghmush clan in Gaza City, for allegedly stealing humanitarian aid and being in contact with Israel, according to unconfirmed Arab media reports.

But my searches don't turn up any 'Arab media' in English that have such reports. I did find a bunch more Israeli media reporting that, and a few Western ones of somewhat dubious reputation, like the *Daily Mail*, which however has a pretty [extensive piece](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-13203775/civil-war-gaza-clan-declares-hamas-legitimate-target.html) on this matter (but most of it is fluff/context/background/filler, not details on the execution claim itself.)

Maybe al-Jazeera and all other (not so few) English language Arab media decided to self-censor on that, or I'm searching for the wrong keywords? What 'Arab media' reported that event?

FWTW, Wikipedia [has](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Doghmush_clan&oldid=1216427074) a one-liner saying that:

> Many Isreali [sic] media outlets falsely reported that Hamas clashed with the family during the war and executed it [sic] leader. The family has denied this and issues a statement on Facebook clarifying the situation.

But the [source](https://nabd.com/s/134327342-c2c991/%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%8B-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%81%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%83-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B3-%D8%A8%D9%82%D8%AA%D9%84-%D9%85%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%AF%D8%BA%D9%85%D8%B4..-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%B2%D9%8A-%D9%84%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%84%D8%A9-%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%8B-%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%87-%D9%87%D8%B0%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%85) cited for that is in Arabic. And it contains a practically identically looking pdf/letter with one the Daily Mail article contains, and which has apparently vastly different claims. So that says little about this, except for the ease of producing such documents, saying whatever.

Comment: Arabic Al Jazeera article here: https://www.aljazeera.net/news/2024/3/17/1210  has a denial by Gaza Media Office, the same pdf of the family denying it, and a tweet bythe president of Euro-Mediterranean Human Rights Monitor from 17 december showing that the family members died in an airstrike.

Answer (score 6):

From [The real reason Israel stormed al-Shifa Hospital yet
again](https://mondoweiss.net/2024/03/the-real-reason-israel-stormed-al-shifa-hospital-yet-again/)
on Mondoweiss on March 18:

> One unsubstantiated rumor was widely circulated on social media in
> Arabic and picked up by the Israeli media: Hamas had supposedly
> executed the unnamed head of the influential Doghmosh clan in Gaza
> for allegedly stealing humanitarian aid and being suspected of
> collaborating with Israel. The Doghmosh clan put out a statement
> strongly denying the claim, asserting that the clan chief had been
> martyred during an Israeli airstrike on November 16, 2023. An
> investigation conducted by Al Jazeera revealed that the name of the
> family’s head (the mukhtar) was on the list of the dead from that
> airstrike.

The article links to [the following
tweet](https://twitter.com/Hanzpal2/status/1768182552194359670) by
@Hanzpal2:

حسب مصادر محلية

حماس اعدمت مختار عائلة دغمش بالاضافة لاخرين من نفس العائلة ونفذت الاعدام بديوان العائلة بمدينة غزة.

العائلة لها سوابق في البلطجة والسطو والقتل

It was tweeted on March 14 08:49 and given its time stamp
it is likely the first online source of the false rumor. Rumours to
sow discord among the enemy is to be expected in a war zone.